# WordPress: using the_title() on posts page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I have a page called 'News' and have set this to be my posts page in my WP settings.

However, whenever I call `the_title` (outside of the loop) it gives me the title from the first blog post, not the page itself.

Is there a way around this?

I've tried using `wp_title('');` but then it gives me the page title + the site title... which isn't what I want either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `single_post_title()` for this. It will output the name of your posts page:

```
<?php single_post_title(); ?>
```

This will output the name. If you do not want to output but return it, you can set the second parameter of the function to false: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_post_title/

```
<?php $pagename = single_post_title( '', false ); ?>
```